# FubuMVC: How do I add a new method a la DisplayFor

Tags: fubumvc

I want to do something like the following in my spark view.

```
@{this.LinkTo("1234")}
```

Which should output something like

```
<a href="domain.tld?var=1234">1234</a>
```

I cannot seem to find a good way to do this.

Most searches for "fubumvc htmlhelpers" end up giving me more pages about htmlhelpers in msmvc.

A plus would be if I could put the code in a separate assembly that I can share between multiple sites.

**Solution**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class FubuPageExtensions
    {
        public static HtmlTag LinkTo(this IFubuPage page, string input)
        {
            return new LinkTag(input, "domain.tld?var={0}".ToFormat(input));
        }
    }
}
```

...and in my spark view

```
<use namespace="MyNamespace" />

${this.LinkTo(Model.Something)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and I solved it this way (not sure if this is the best approach, but it worked for my scenario).

The idea is to create an extension method on the *IFubuPage* interface, which returns a new *HtmlTag* object. Please note that I'm using the Razor view engine, not entirely sure if this would work for Spark as well.

So for example, the following code would produce a new <abbr /> tag:

```
public static HtmlTag TimeAgoFor(this IFubuPage page, DateTime input)
{
    return new HtmlTag("abbr")
        .Title(input.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK"))
        .AddClass("timeago")
        .Text(input.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"));
    }
}
```

In your scenario, I think this should suffice then:

```
public static HtmlTag LinkTo(this IFubuPage page, string input)
{
     return new LinkTag(input, "domain.tld?var={0}".ToFormat(input));
}
```

Comment: I have actually already tried this, but I just get a "Dynamic view compilation failed" stating that my method does not exist. I have not done anything other that creating the extension method within my own namespace. I do not know if Fubu would "magically" pick up my extension method, but it does not seem to do so.

Comment: In the generated view / error screen do you see your namespace getting imported? If not you'll need to import it.

Comment: My namespace is not referenced, but how do I get it imported? The <use namespace="..." /> is not currently accounted for. http://readthedocs.org/docs/fubumvc/en/latest/topics/viewengines/spark/usingspark.html#fubumvc-spark-limitations

Comment: Apparently the documentation is out of date. I just tried the <use namespace=".."/> and it works. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: I'm not sure if that's accurate or up to date. We typically add our references in the _global.spark and it works fine. I haven't tried in the specific views template, but I would give it a try in both. If it does work let us know and we'll update the docs to reflect that.

Comment: FWIW, the <use namespace=".."/> is accounted for in any references in your Spark View. It is NOT accounted for in your <viewdata model=".." /> declaration. That's what this is "supposed" to mean:

"The full type name must be specified in the Spark file. The <use namespace="..." /> is not currently accounted for."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your "FubuPageExtensions" namespace in your spark file.

As noted in the comments, use a "_global.spark" file in the Shared directory so all .spark files have the extensions namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would appeal to you but you can also declare your helpers in one of the default namespaces that the fubu.spark viewengine supports, e.g.:

```
namespace FubuMVC.Core.UI
{
public static class MyHelper{
public static HtmlTag LinkTo(this IFubuPage page, string input)
{
     return new LinkTag(input, "domain.tld?var={0}".ToFormat(input));
}
}
}
```